# How to make scrollbar appear on modal when content is large, and disappear when content is small?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

## Introduction

I have a React project in which I have a modal component. Here is how it looks (the content of the modal does not matter):

[image]

Here is what is looks like when I set `overflow-y` to `scroll`, and the content is small (as you can see, there is a tiny inset on the right side of the modal):

[image]

Here is what it looks like when I set `overflow-y` to `scroll`, but with a larger amount of content (as you can see, it is scrollable):

[image]

## Question

How do I get rid of the little inset displayed in the second picture, while still setting `overflow-y` to `scroll`. In other words, how can I configure it so that when the content is small, there is no scrollbar and when the content is large, there is a scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `overflow-y` to `auto`

This will make the scrollbar to appear only when the content is very long and the scrollbar will be needed, or else the scrollbar will not be there.